# Is aliasing of mutable references correct in unsafe code?

Tags: rust, mutable, unsafe, pointer-aliasing

In *unsafe* code, is it correct to have several mutable references (not pointers) to the same array, as long as they are not used to write to the same indices?

### Context

I would like to yield several (distinct) mutable views of an underlying array, that I can modify from different threads.

If the disjoint parts are contiguous, this is trivial, by just calling [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) on the slice:

```rust
let mut v = [1, 2, 3, 4];
{
    let (left, right) = v.split_at_mut(2);
    left[0] = 5;
    right[0] = 6;
}
assert!(v == [5, 2, 6, 4]);
```

But I also want to expose non-contiguous disjoint parts. For simplicity, let's say we want to retrieve a mutable "view" for even indices, and another mutable "view" for odd indices.

Contrary to `split_at_mut()`, we could not retrieve two mutable references (we want a safe abstraction!), so we use two structure instances instead, exposing only mutable access to even (resp. odd) indices:

```
let data = &mut [0i32; 11];
let (mut even, mut odd) = split_fields(data);
// …
```

With some *unsafe* code, it is easy to get such a safe abstraction. Here is [a possible implementation](https://github.com/rom1v/rust-split/):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct SliceField<'a> {
    ptr: *mut i32,
    len: usize,
    field: usize,
    marker: PhantomData<&'a mut i32>,
}

impl SliceField<'_> {
    fn inc(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            for i in (self.field..self.len).step_by(2) {
                *self.ptr.add(i) += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fn dec(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            for i in (self.field..self.len).step_by(2) {
                *self.ptr.add(i) -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for SliceField<'_> {}

fn split_fields(array: &mut [i32]) -> (SliceField<'_>, SliceField<'_>) {
    (
        SliceField {
            ptr: array.as_mut_ptr(),
            len: array.len(),
            field: 0,
            marker: PhantomData,
        },
        SliceField {
            ptr: array.as_mut_ptr(),
            len: array.len(),
            field: 1,
            marker: PhantomData,
        },
    )
}

fn main() {
    let data = &mut [0i32; 11];
    {
        let (mut even, mut odd) = split_fields(data);
        rayon::join(|| even.inc(), || odd.dec());
    }
    // this prints [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

So far, so good.

### Problem

However, accessing a raw pointer is far for convenient: contrary to slices, we cannot use operator `[]` or iterators.

```rust
unsafe {
    for i in (self.field..self.len).step_by(2) {
        *self.ptr.add(i) += 1;
    }
}
```

The obvious idea is to convert locally the raw pointer to a slice in the unsafe implementation:

```rust
let slice = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.ptr, self.len) };
```

Then we could, for example, rewrite our implementation in functional style:

```rust
slice.iter_mut().skip(self.field).step_by(2).for_each(|x| *x += 1);
```

For this sample, it may not worth it, but for more complex code, it could be far more convenient to use slices instead of raw pointers.

### Question

Is this correct?

This obviously violates the [borrowing rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references): two threads may simultaneously hold a mutable reference to the very same memory location. However, they may never write to the same indices.

Mutable reference aliasing is not listed as an [unsafe superpower](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html), but the list is not presented as exhaustive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is aliasing of mutable references correct

No, it is **never correct** to alias mutable references (mutable *pointers* are a more nuanced concept). That's breaking one of the principal [rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references).

None of the qualifications you've provided matter — you cannot have mutable aliasing of references. The code being inside of an `unsafe` block makes no difference. Doing so is *automatic and instant undefined behavior*.

---

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = [42, 84];
    let x_raw = &mut x as *mut _;

    let x_even: &mut [i32; 2] = unsafe { &mut *x_raw };
    let x_odd: &mut [i32; 2] = unsafe { &mut *x_raw };

    println!("{}, {}", x_even[0], x_odd[1]);
}
```

Miri states:

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error: Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1772)) does not exist on the stack
 --> src/main.rs:8:24
  |
8 |     println!("{}, {}", x_even[0], x_odd[1]);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^ Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1772)) does not exist on the stack
  |
  = note: inside call to `main` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:34
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:53
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:297:40
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::do_call::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:293:5
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::<i32, [closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe]>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panic.rs:388:9
  = note: inside call to `std::panic::catch_unwind::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:25
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:5
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start::<()>`
```

While an [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) can help you build safe abstractions, you still have to adhere to the rules of references. Replacing a type with `UnsafeCell` will *not* make things magically work:

```
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

fn main() {
    let x = UnsafeCell::new([42, 84]);

    let x_even: &mut [i32; 2] = unsafe { &mut *x.get() };
    let x_odd: &mut [i32; 2] = unsafe { &mut *x.get() };

    println!("{}, {}", x_even[0], x_odd[1]);
}
```

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error: Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1776)) does not exist on the stack
 --> src/main.rs:9:24
  |
9 |     println!("{}, {}", x_even[0], x_odd[1]);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^ Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1776)) does not exist on the stack
  |
  = note: inside call to `main` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:34
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:53
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:297:40
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::do_call::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:293:5
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::<i32, [closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe]>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panic.rs:388:9
  = note: inside call to `std::panic::catch_unwind::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:25
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:5
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start::<()>`
```

`UnsafeCell`'s docs explicitly call this out:

> A `&mut T` reference may be released to safe code provided neither other `&mut T` nor `&T` co-exist with it. A `&mut T` must always be unique.

In fact, even if your slices don't start at the same point but they overlap somehow, that's also aliasing and undefined behavior:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = [0, 1, 2];
    let x_raw = &mut x as *mut [i32];

    let x_0: &mut [i32] = unsafe { &mut (*x_raw)[0..2] };
    let x_1: &mut [i32] = unsafe { &mut (*x_raw)[1..3] };

    if x_0 == x_1 {
        println!("They are equal");
    }
}
```

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error: Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1807)) does not exist on the stack
    --> /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/cmp.rs:1041:65
     |
1041 |         fn eq(&self, other: &&'b mut B) -> bool { PartialEq::eq(*self, *other) }
     |                                                                 ^^^^^ Borrow being dereferenced (Uniq(1807)) does not exist on the stack
     |
note: inside call to `std::cmp::impls::<impl std::cmp::PartialEq<&'b mut B> for &'a mut A><[i32], [i32]>::eq` at src/main.rs:8:8
    --> src/main.rs:8:8
     |
8    |     if x_0 == x_1 {
     |        ^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: inside call to `main` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:34
     = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:53
     = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:297:40
     = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::do_call::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:293:5
     = note: inside call to `std::panicking::try::<i32, [closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe]>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panic.rs:388:9
     = note: inside call to `std::panic::catch_unwind::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1900 ~ std[82ff]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:25
     = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:64:5
     = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start::<()>`
```

Comment: @rodrigo FWIW, I [filed an issue for the discrepancy](https://github.com/solson/miri/issues/628).

Comment: Cool! In the last example, does it mean that, if the slices did not overlap whatsoever, it would be OK?

Comment: @rsalmei yes, I believe so. That's how [`slice::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) works, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) states:

> The `UnsafeCell<T>` type is the only legal way to obtain aliasable data that is considered mutable.
>   [...]
>   The compiler makes optimizations based on the knowledge that `&T` is not mutably aliased or mutated, and that `&mut T` is unique.

So no, what you are trying to is not valid, unless you use an `UnsafeCell`.